# SharePoint CAML Query: Value does not fall into expected range

Tags: c#, sharepoint, caml

I've created the following method in a class which is intended to fetch all items in a SharePont list and load them into my entity:

```
public List<ItemEntity> FetchItems(SPList list)
{
    // build the CAML query of field names that we wish to retreive
    var query = new SPQuery
        {
            ViewFields = string.Concat("<FieldRef Name='Modified' />",
                                        "<FieldRef Name='Modified By' />",
                                        "<FieldRef Name='Created' />",
                                        "<FieldRef Name='Created By' />")
        };

        SPListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(query);

        return (from SPListItem item in items
                select Load("", // item id
                            "", // content type
                            "", // display name
                            "", // name
                            "", // title
                            "", // url
                            "", // author
                            "", // editor
                            Convert.ToDateTime(item["Modified"]), // date time modified
                            item["Modified By"].ToString(), // modified by
                            Convert.ToDateTime(item["Created"]), // date time created
                            item["Created By"].ToString() // created by
                    )).ToList();
}
```

For some reason that I don't understand it's throwing the following error:

> Value does not fall within the expected range.

I thought this could be something to do with the results returned by my CAML query, but even then I restricted it down to meta data fields (which I believe should exist on every file) and unfortunately I'm still receiving the error. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are missing the correct internal names of some built-in fields.

Try to use:

```
item["Author"].ToString() instead of item["Created By"].ToString() and
item["Editor"].ToString() instead of item["Modified By"].ToString()
```

For a full reference of sharepoint 2010 internal field names I usually consult the following link:
http://sharepointmalarkey.wordpress.com/2010/10/12/sharepoint-internal-field-names-sharepoint-2010/